# "Mark as favourite" feature for a web page

Tags: html, joomla

(I'm quite new to programming so forgive me for any incorrect terms! HTML and CSS are my strenghts.)

I'm currently working on a Joomla website for a music festival. One of its pages contains a schedule with a list of performing acts.

My ambitious goal is to build a feature that makes my website's users able to **mark certain acts as their favourites**. In practice, clicking an icon would give it a visual highlight or something like that. The ideal situation would be that the user shouldn't have to sign in to save one's choises. I guess the solution would have something to do with the browser's local storage?

[Here's one example](http://www.flowfestival.com/site2012/aikataulut/index.html) for what I mean. (This is NOT my site, just an example of something I'm looking for).

Can anyone help me to get started?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This extension, http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/my-shortlist , should help with little or no modifications to the template.

If the above doesn't help, then you can the JED (the Joomla Extensions Directory) for an extension that is better suited to your needs.